# Excel VBA: Resize sub arrays within an array of arrays without declaring variable for each sub array

Tags: excel, vba, jagged-arrays

I have a tab delimited 2-dimensional data (copied from another Excel file on a remote system) in clipboard, which contains about 20 columns and can contain any number of rows.

I want to read the data into a VBA array of arrays, where each sub-array represents the complete data of one column from the 2-D data in the clipboard. The objective is to paste the data into a local Excel file, which has some hidden columns, by skipping the hidden columns while pasting. I want to use the array of arrays approach, so that while pasting, I can assign a whole column sub-array to the Excel Range.

I declare an array of arrays for 20 columns:

```
Dim allColsData(20) As Variant
```

But I do not want to be declaring 20 variables for each sub-array column, which I need to dynamically resize as I add each row from clipboard into this array allColsData.

I am new to Excel VBA and need help on how to populate the array allColsData by dynamically resizing each sub array, without declaring 20 array variables.

**My question is:**

What is the syntax to resize each sub array of allColsData without declaring variable for each sub array?

I can manage the code for reading from the clipboard and parsing into a 2-D array, first by splitting based on new line and then splitting each line on tab character.

Comment: The technical term for an array of arrays is 'jagged aray'. You will have to paste your data as a 2d array before you can convert. Thus I'd recommend pasting into a temporary hidden worksheet and just copy ranges as you need.

Comment: The Excel file to which I want to paste is a macro controlled Excel file. I cannot add any hidden sheet.

Comment: In which case, if you can, copy column by column from the remote spreadsheet into a VBA array or into your target spreadsheet.

Comment: How can the VBA code running on local system copy column by column data from a remote worksheet which is opened inside an RDP session

Comment: Could you share the code where you read and parse into a 2D array? Not sure if it is best to modify your process or just continue with your 2D array.

Comment: Failure to adequately describe the constraints under which you are working often leads to unhelpful suggestions.  I'd suggest you consider moderating the tone of your comments to those who are volunteering to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Jag Clipboard Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Tests the JagClipBoardColumns function.
' Calls:        JagClipBoardColumns
'                   RefColumn,GetRange.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub JagClipBoardColumnsTEST()
    
    Dim cData As Variant: cData = JagClipBoardColumns
    If IsEmpty(cData) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To UBound(cData)
        Debug.Print "Array " & c & " has " & UBound(cData(c)) & " rows."
    Next c

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Adds a new one-worksheet workbook and pastes the contents
'               of the clipboard starting with cell 'A1'. Returns the values
'               of each column from a given row ('FirstRow') to the bottom-most
'               non-empty row in a 2D one-based array of a jagged array
'               finally closing the workbook.
' Calls:        RefColumn,GetRange.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function JagClipboardColumns( _
    Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "JagClipboardColumns"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    
    ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim cData As Variant: ReDim cData(1 To cCount)
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        Set crg = RefColumn(ws.Cells(FirstRow, c))
        cData(c) = GetRange(crg)
    Next c
        
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    JagClipboardColumns = cData

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks for going out of your way and posting complete code for an alternate solution. If I have follow up questions, I will create separate thread.